# Cardinality of Sets and injections

Tags: functions, cardinals

Let A,B,C,D sets. if |A| $\le$|B| and |B| < |C|, show that |A| < |C|

*Proof:*

*Case1:*

suppose |A| < |B|

then there exists injection f: A$\to$B

and |B| < |C|

then there exists injection g: B$\to$C

let h(x) = f(g(x)) = h:A$\to$C

h(x) is an injection because it is the composition of two injections, thus, |A| < |C|

*Case2:*

suppose |A| = |B|

then there exists a bijection f:A$\to$B

(repeat for |B|<|C|)

let h(x) = f(g(x)) = h:A$\to$C

h(x) is an injection

thus |A| < |C|

This is my proof and I'm not sure I'm doing it correctly. I'm not sure this is the correct procedure

Comment: You didn't write the composed maps in the right order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the right general ideas, but your proof is not quite right. In both cases, you are finding an injection from $A$ to $C$, and concluding $|A| < |C|$. However, such an injection only allows you to conclude that $|A| \leq |C|$. The canonical way to show $|A| < |C|$ is to find an injection from $A$ to $C$, and to show that there *cannot* be an injection from $C$ to $A$.

Here's how I would do it. What we know is that there is an injection $f : A \to B$ and an injection $g : B \to C$. We also know that there is no injection $C \to B$. Immediately, we have that $g \circ f : A \to C$ is an injection (as you observed), so $|A| \leq |C|$. To show that the inequality is strict, assume for contradiction that there is an injection $h : C \to A$. In that case, $f \circ h : C \to B$ is an injection (since it is a composition of injections). This is a contradiction, since we were told that no such injection exists. Thus concludes the proof.